# Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz wifi adapter not working in ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS after the last update

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, updates

I have dual boot system with win 10 pro and in ubuntu my wifi adapter is not even recognized when I first boot, only after a reboot. it has been working well until now. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, Pilot6, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Intel Wi-Fi adapter in dual-boot with Windows, Windows Fast Startup feature should be disabled.

Windows doesn't really shut down properly with this feature enabled and leaves the Wi-Fi device in a wrong state for another OS.